# How to configure custom main class using YAML in wildfly swarm application

Tags: configuration, yaml, program-entry-point, wildfly-swarm

I am trying to build a Wildfly Swarm application using custom main class specified in plugin configuration ( as shown below )

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2018.3.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>rnd.web.service.rest.App</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But during build/run is show deprecation warning/information (see below) with reference to documentation. But the documentation does not provide any details on how to implement it.

> Custom main() usage is intended to be deprecated in a future release
>   and is no longer supported,  please refer to
>   http://docs.wildfly-swarm.io for YAML configuration that replaces it.

If someone has encountered and implemented it. Please share the approach and correct reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the deprecation warning says, it's not the `<mainClass>` setting that's deprecated, it's the entire usage of custom `main` method. All the configuration you do in your `main` method, you should be able to do with the YAML configuration. If you find something missing, then that's a bug.